# Determine number of digits of precision used in a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how many actually used decimal places I have inside a number.

So for example if I have  0.64 it will be 2 decimal, if I have 0.604 it will be 3 decimal.
But if I search for first zero it will find 0 between 6 and 4. I tried using RIGHT to search from right zero but didn't work.

Why that? Because I need to know how much 0 I need to multiply to my decimal to have an integer but at same time I need to know this number of 0 so I put inside another field.

So for example, if I have 0.64 I will multiply to 100 so I will have 64 in a filed and 100 in another.
If I have 0.604 I will multiply to 1000 so I will have 604 in a field and 1000 in another.

I'm doing a migration from an old ERP to SAP.

Instruction that I'm trying

```
declare @val decimal(10,6),
        @var varchar(50),
        @point int,
        @zero int,
        @calc int,
        @UMREZ int,
        @UMREN int

set @val = 0.604 
set @var = trim(str(@val, 10, 10))
set @point = cast(CHARINDEX('.', @var) as int)
set @zero = cast(right(CHARINDEX('0', @var, @point), 8) as int)
set @calc = @zero - @point - 1

set @umrez = case when @calc = 0 then 1 
                  when @calc = 1 then 10 
                  when @calc = 2 then 100
                  when @calc = 3 then 1000
                  when @calc = 4 then 10000
                  when @calc = 5 then 100000
                  when @calc = 6 then 1000000
         end
set @UMREN = @val * @UMREZ

select @var, @point, @zero, @calc, @UMREZ, @UMREN
```

Comment: Why do you need this? `I'm doing a migration from an old ERP to SAP.` doesn't SAP handle decimals? Are you trying to fix a *real* SAP limitation? ERP implementation hacks cause huge problems for decade*s*.

Comment: Hacks and SAP is a bit of tautology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to `REVERSE` the decimal and use `patindex`

```
SELECT POWER(10, PATINDEX('%.%', REVERSE(val)) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%', REVERSE(val)))
from 
(values(0.604000),
       (0.600000),
       (0.000000),
       (4.000000)
)v(val)
```

The `PATINDEX('%.%', REVERSE(val))` can just be replaced with `7` if you are working with `decimal(x, 6)` and don't have to worry about it changing in the future (e.g. as this a one off task).

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/67Zw9FTZ)

Comment: I'd be more interested in the *why*. SAP can handle decimals.

Comment: I can't help you with the why. You need to ask Andrea about that

Comment: I'm dealing with implementer hacks myself right now. The question triggered a lot of alarm bells.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've never had the "pleasure" of working with SAP so don't know if there is any legit reason for this

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @val decimal(10,6),
        @valS varchar(50),
        @var varchar(50),
        @point int,
        @UMREZ int,
        @UMREN int

set @val = 0.604
set @valS = convert(varchar(50),convert(float,@val))
set @point = CHARINDEX('.', @valS, 0)
set @var = substring(@valS,1+@point,len(@valS))

set @umrez = power(10,len(@var))

set @UMREN = @val * @UMREZ

select @valS, @var, @point, @UMREZ, @UMREN
```